# Cannot Convert From One Binding to Another

Tags: swiftui

I'm developing a screen in SwiftUI and have the following code:

```
...

@EnvironmentObject var externalState: MainStateObject

...

SelectOptionPopover(options: $externalState.depots,
                            selectedOption: selectedDepot,
                            prompt: "Depot: ")

...
```

`SelectOptionPopover` is a view that I created to handle a variety of popovers. For the options, it expects an array of `[SelectOptionPopoverOption]`, which is declared like this:

```
protocol SelectOptionPopoverOption {
    var displayName: String { get }
}
```

Now, the issue I have is that when I pass an array of `SelectOptionPopoverOptions`, it works just fine. But if I pass an array of another type that *conforms* to SelectOptionPopoverOptions, the conversion fails with something like:

`'Binding<[Depot]>' is not convertible to 'Binding<[SelectOptionPopoverOption]>'`

These may be the exact same objects, but work when they're identified as `SelectOptionPopoverOption`s but not when identified as a `Depot`s.

I can work around this by using arrays of `SelectedOptionPopoverOption` and casting them as needed, but it would sure be cleaner to be able to use the conforming types instead.

Any ideas on how I could use the more specific types instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare and adopt your custom `SelectOptionPopover` view as generics

```
struct SelectOptionPopover<T>: View where T: SelectOptionPopoverOption {
    @Binding var options: [T]
    ...
```